# Xamarin Deploy To Android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

So I got Xamarin onto Visual Studio, and did the Xamarin.Forms template. I would expect that when I connect my phone to the computer I would be able to deploy to my phone, like the mobile development with C++ workload. When I connected it, though, it still only had the option to deploy to the Android Emulator.

The Android Emulator takes up  a lot of space on my hard drive, so I'd like to just deploy it to my phone. When I use the Mobile Development with C++ workload, it shows my phone on the deployment thing, but with Xamarin it doesn't.

Does anyone know how I can deploy to my phone using Xamarin, and not install the Emulator?

Comment: You can get about without having the emulator, but you will still need the SDKs because that is how your computer communicates with an android device. I think the bare minimum would be `adb` and whatever dependencies it has.

Comment: have you enabled your Android device for development?  Do you have the necessary USB drivers installed?

Comment: @Jason yes I have development mode on, etc. As I said above, it works with the mobile development with C++ workload, but not with Xamarin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

;)

If you encounter this problem, make sure you have selected this:
[image]

Otherwise, Xamarin will make you install the emulator.